# Xpath Get data from xml column with out cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, xpath, xquery

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 with this structure:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

-- DDL and sample data population, start

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[tblStepList];



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStepList](
    [listid] [int] ,
    [Data] [xml] NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.tblStepList (Listid, [Data]) VALUES

(1, N'<Steplist>
  <Step>
    <StepId>e36a3450-1c8f-44da-b4d0-58e5bfe2a987</StepId>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <IsComplete>false</IsComplete>
    <TextReadingId>10</TextReadingId>      
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepId>4078c1b1-71ea-4578-ba61-d2f6a5126ba1</StepId>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
    <TextReadingName>reading1</TextReadingName>
    <TextReadingId>12</TextReadingId>
  </Step>
</Steplist>'),
(2, N'<Steplist>
  <Step>
    <StepId>d9e42387-56e3-40a1-9698-e89c930d98d1</StepId>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <IsComplete>false</IsComplete>
    <TextReadingName>bug-8588_Updated3</TextReadingName>   
    <TextReadingId>0</TextReadingId>  
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepId>e5eaf947-24e1-4d3b-a92a-d6a90841293b</StepId>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
     <TextReadingId>1</TextReadingId>  
  </Step>
</Steplist>'),
(3, N'<Steplist>
  <Step>
    <StepId>d9e42387-56e3-40a1-9698-58e5bfe2a987</StepId>
    <Rank>1</Rank>
    <IsComplete>true</IsComplete>
    <TextReadingName>bug-8588_Updated3</TextReadingName>   
    <TextReadingId>1</TextReadingId>  
  </Step>
  <Step>
    <StepId>e5eaf947-24e1-4d3b-a92a-d2f6a5126ba1</StepId>
    <Rank>2</Rank>
     <TextReadingId>1</TextReadingId>  
  </Step>
</Steplist>');


-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

I want sql  query that can give me the rows of listids where textreadingid = 1 exists in the data xml.

Which means in this case my result will be a table with   ListIds 2, 3

What I tried below works but uses cross apply which was super slow in large data.
I want a soltion with out cross apply.

```
select  distinct Listid from
            (
            SELECT 
            s.Listid,
    x.XmlCol.value('(TextReadingId)[1]', 'int') as [TextReadingId]
        
    FROM tblStepList s 
    CROSS APPLY s.Data.nodes('/Steplist/Step') x(XmlCol)
    ) a
where TextReadingId = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The slow bit is not the `CROSS APPLY .nodes` but the `DISTINCT`.

Be that as it may, you can do this using the `.exist` function

```sql
select
  Listid
FROM tblStepList s 
WHERE s.Data.exist('/Steplist/Step/TextReadingId[text()="1"]') = 1
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=604aab4ce37065e2cc06d03673a2417f)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `sql` and `xquery` you are using here, but the XPath expression to select `Steplists` you are looking for could be something like the following:

```xml
"//Steplist[.//TextReadingId[text()='1']]"
```